# Kendo Grid - Auto Width & Scrollable

Tags: jquery, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a large Kendo Grid with dynamic column definitions. My current implementation is using **scrollable**  grid with all fixed-widths columns. Though, came up the need to have some columns with **auto** width while others with fixed length. I noticed that when I have some auto width with fixed length columns, they just don't show up in the grid.

I know that Auto Width and Scrollable grids are mutual exclusive features, but wanted to know if anyone had found a solution to this issue. I've been tweaking the grid a lot to get extra features out of it. My only solution right now is that I have a script to parse rows and auto-expand those that needs to.. But its an expensive operation and slows down the user experience.

Any ideas?

Thanks everyone.

**EDIT:**
I would like to be able to have these few auto-width columns to fit on one line. To be more specific I have fixed length columns with numbers and some others with descriptions. I would like to have these columns to fit on one line and not be wrapped or hidden. That is, having my grid scrolling horizontally.

Comment: I think that what left over from the grid width after subtracting the sum of the fixed width columns is divided among the auto width fields.

Comment: You are right, this is why it gets a zero length. I need to defeat that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ross is right...if the width of the grid is too small, the autowidth columns get assigned the remaining width after the fixed columns have been allocated.  This will often be zero and then you are stuck.

My workaround(HACK!!!) for this is to set a min-width on the grid that is the sum of the fixed widths plus an extra amount that will can be equally divided between the autowidth columns.  Then I call a custom ensureMinWidth() function that fixes up the width of the Grid's table and header elements based on the min-width so that the autowidth columns get some space allocated to them.

It's hacky, but it prevents columns from disappearing.

Setting the min-width:

```
<style>
/* Force initial min-width to fit all the columns so that the Title column
    (which is set to take up the remaining space) will not disappear when remaining space is 0 on initial screen load.
    Grid.ensureMinWidth() javascript will deal with it at runtime.
*/
#grid .k-grid-header-wrap > table, /* header table */
#grid .k-grid-content table, /* data table, no virtual scrolling */
#grid .k-virtual-scrollable-wrap table /* data table, with virtual scrolling */ {
    min-width: 600px; /* Width of fixed columns plus enough space so that autowidth columns don't disappear, i.e. min column width of auto columns */
}
 </style>
```

The helper function:

```
<script>
/* Ensures that a grid will that has too many columns to fit in the viewport will not shrink dynamic width
    columns to 0 if there is no space left and then makes sure that the column resizing continues to function
    without weird jumping around/misalignment with the cursor that the out-of-the-box solution creates. 
    NOTE:
    1. MUST be used in conjunction with the grid tables being given an initial min-width at design-time.
    2. Due to the way Kendo binds the Grid's resizable with ajax data, this must be called on every dataBound
        rather than just during Grid initialization. */
kendo.ui.Grid.prototype.ensureMinWidth = function () {
    if (this.resizable) {
        this.resizable.bind("resize", function (e) {
            var minTableWidth,
                th = $(e.currentTarget).data("th"),
                grid = th.closest(".k-grid").getKendoGrid();

            if (e.x.delta > 0) {
                minTableWidth = grid.tbody.closest("table").width();
            }
            else {
                minTableWidth = grid.tbody.closest("table").width() + e.x.delta;
            }
            if (grid.options.scrollable) {
                grid.thead.closest("table").css({ "min-width": minTableWidth });
            }
            grid.tbody.closest("table").css({ "min-width": minTableWidth });
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

And then you just call the ensureMinWidth() in the Grid's dataBound event.

The setting of the min-width alone may work for you but I found the need for the helper function on my forms where I resize the grid to take up the space remaining in the browser viewport...your results may vary.

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/IlUYun

Comment: This way it will ensure a minimum width for the auto-width columns. Although I would like to be able to have these few columns to fit on one line. To be more specific I have fixed length columns with numbers and some others with descriptions. I would like to have these columns to fit on one line and not be wrapped or hidden. So having a minimum width kinda comes back to my old solution where I had fixed width columns for these descriptions, if it makes sense.

Comment: If you must really have that functionality, then your brute-force, slow method is really all that is available(unless you spend an inordinate amount of time rolling your own perfect, custom solution...but I'm sure your time is better spent on "real" functionality.  Here's a Telerik Support post on essentially the same topic: http://www.telerik.com/forums/autofitcolumn-functionality#ZdnH9ST4t0S5dPZK7QcFbA